# Can´t do this to sum digits in a string python

Tags: python-3.x

```
sumNum = 0
while sumNum < 20:
num = input("Introduza um numero: ")
sumNum = int(num[1]) + int(num[2]) + int(num[3])
print(sumNum)
```

cannot seem to do this to print the sum of the digits on a number
this prints ou the following error:
sumNum = int(num[1]) + int(num[2]) + int(num[3])
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: change `sumNum = int(num[1]) + int(num[2]) + int(num[3])` to `sumNum = sum([int(i) for i in num])`

Comment: it worked thank you

Answer (score -1):

Check your indenting and I would recommend splitting it:

```
sumNum = 0
while sumNum < 20:
   num = input("Introduza um numero: ").split()
   if len(num)===3:
       sumNum = int(num[1]) + int(num[2]) + int(num[3])
       print(sumNum)
```